# SQL - min() gets the lowest value, max() the highest, what if I want the 2nd (or 5th or nth) lowest value?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The problem I'm trying to solve is that I have a table like this:

a and b refer to point on a different table. distance is the distance between the points.

```
| id | a_id | b_id | distance | delete |
| 1  |  1   |   1  |  1       |   0    |
| 2  |  1   |   2  |  0.2345  |   0    |
| 3  |  1   |   3  |  100     |   0    |
| 4  |  2   |   1  |  1343.2  |   0    |
| 5  |  2   |   2  |  0.45    |   0    |
| 6  |  2   |   3  |  110     |   0    |
....
```

The important column I'm looking is a_id. If I wanted to keep the closet b for each a, I could do something like this:

```
update mytable set delete = 1 from (select a_id, min(distance) as dist from table group by a_id) as x where a_gid = a_gid and distance > dist;
delete from mytable where delete = 1;
```

Which would give me a result table like this:

```
| id | a_id | b_id | distance | delete |
| 1  |  1   |   1  |  1       |   0    |
| 5  |  2   |   2  |  0.45    |   0    |
....
```

i.e. I need one row for each value of a_id, and that row should have the lowest value of distance for each a_id.

However I want to keep the 10 closest points for each a_gid. I could do this with a plpgsql function but I'm curious if there is a more SQL-y way.

min() and max() return the smallest and largest, if there was an aggregate function like nth(), which'd return the nth largest/smallest value then I could do this in similar manner to the above.

I'm using PostgeSQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    SELECT  a_id, (
        SELECT b_id
        FROM mytable mib
        WHERE mib.a_id = ma.a_id
        ORDER BY
            dist DESC
        LIMIT 1 OFFSET s
        ) AS b_id
    FROM    (
        SELECT DISTINCT a_id
        FROM mytable mia
        ) ma, generate_series (1, 10) s
    ) ab
WHERE   b_id IS NOT NULL
```

Checked on PostgreSQL 8.3

Answer (score 4):

I love postgres, so it took it as a challenge the second I saw this question.

So, for the table:

```
    Table "pg_temp_29.foo"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 value  | integer |
```

With the values:

```
 SELECT value FROM foo ORDER BY value;
 value 
-------
     0
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
     9
    14
    20
    32
(13 rows)
```

You can do a:

```
SELECT value FROM foo ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET X
```

Where X = 0 for the highest value, 1 for the second highest, 2... And so forth.

This can be further embedded in a subquery to retrieve the value needed. So, to use the dataset provided in the original question we can get the a_ids with the top ten lowest distances by doing:

```
SELECT a_id, distance FROM mytable
 WHERE id IN
  (SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE t1.a_id = t2.a_id
   ORDER BY distance LIMIT 10);
 ORDER BY a_id, distance;

 a_id | distance 
------+----------
    1 |   0.2345
    1 |        1
    1 |      100
    2 |     0.45
    2 |      110
    2 |   1342.2
```

Comment: Dang, I should have given you an example from the dataset you provided.

Comment: That won't work, because I want the lowest value for each value of a_id.

Comment: If you remove the DESC (for descending) you will get a list of the lowest values: SELECT value FROM foo ORDER BY value LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;
Anyways, my hope was to demonstrate the principal with a simpler dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Does PostgreSQL have the analytic function rank()?  If so try:

```
select a_id, b_id, distance
from
( select a_id, b_id, distance, rank() over (partition by a_id order by distance) rnk
  from mytable
) where rnk <= 10;
```

Comment: Postgres doesn't have this functon, but you're on the right track and your suggestion is helping me find the answer.

Comment: Now, in PostgreSQL 9.1, there is a rank() function within Window Functions. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html

Answer (score 0):

This SQL should find you the Nth lowest salary should work in SQL Server, MySQL, DB2, Oracle, Teradata, and almost any other RDBMS: (note: low performance because of subquery)

```
SELECT * /*This is the outer query part */
FROM mytable tbl1
WHERE (N-1) = ( /* Subquery starts here */
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(tbl2.distance))
FROM mytable tbl2
WHERE tbl2.distance < tbl1.distance)
```

The most important thing to understand in the query above is that the subquery is evaluated each and every time a row is processed by the outer query. In other words, the inner query can not be processed independently of the outer query since the inner query uses the tbl1 value as well.

In order to find the Nth lowest value, we just find the value that has exactly N-1 values lower than itself.